# How can I run a Docker container that can reach LAN?

Tags: docker, networking, lan, cidr

Given that I have a Docker image, which defines a container that has a server inside, listening on some port, I want to be able to deploy it in LAN so that the server itself can reach out to any other computing instance or smart device within the given range of private IP addresses, that defines the private network.

How can I achieve that? The goal is to have this deployment automated and to be able to deploy in different LANs with minimal manual intervention.

Comment: Is using the [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) with `--net host` an option here? Do you need something like [macvlan networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/)?

Comment: unfortunately, connecting to host is not enough here. Macvlan networks look closer to what I need. To be honest, I feel like I just need to define a new bridge network and run my containers inside of it, but I'm not sure how to configure it properly

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special at all (you definitely don't need `--net host`).  Docker provides a NAT setup and the container should be able to reach anything the host can reach.  Can you give a more detailed example of something that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concept of port mapping. 
Just map the listening port of the server in docker image to any port of host machine during run.

```
  docker run -p <host_machine_port>:<docker_server_listening_port> <image_name>
```

Comment: Port mapping won't help if I want to make request from the container process to devices in the private network. Mapping will make the container reachable, but I need to make other LAN based resources reachable from within the container

Comment: I think you need to write routing rules in iptables of docker https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-local-network-from-docker-container/48062/4